# How to delete model data on button click? - Django

Tags: python, django

I have the following button: `<a style="float:right; margin:5px; color: white;" href="" class="btn btn-success" >Accept</a>`

When the button is clicked on by the user, I want to delete data that is associated with the `pk`

For example, when the button is clicked, I want to pass the `{{donation.pk}}` into a function and delete the `Donation` that is associated with it

I have done so much research but I can not find out a way to do this.

Comment: Well, you cannot directly call python function from html. But, you have some request to be sent to the server. And, that request decides what to do. In your case, what you can do is, create a path which will take `donation_id`. Then, that path will have the views where you will delete the donation.

Comment: Thank you, would it be possible for you to create an answer showing me how to do it? If everything works, I can Buy You A Coffe

Comment: I have added the answer. Have a look and ask me if you cannot undersand any part

Comment: Ok thank you, I will take a look and get back to you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to understand that the tag you are using is **client side** which means client can access that easily. And, another part of the web development is **server side** which is exact opposite. Or, it is the scripts (lets say) which only server have access. In your case, your computer is hosting the localhost:8000 from your local server and the server is django's default server.

Now, we have understand two main parts, it will be easy to break things down. What you are wanting is to delete the donation with id, which is in the backend or which is in our database. And, database are only access through server in our case, django will communicate with the database.

So, to delete the donation, you will send request to server to ask for deletion of donation. To send that request you have many methods like GET, POST, PUT and so on. In our case we will go with **GET**.

Firstly your client side will be able to send request with:

```
<a style="float:right; margin:5px; color: white;" href="/donations/{{donation.pk}}/delete/" class="btn btn-success" >Accept</a>
```

Now, we will make a path or route in *urls.py*. Like:

```
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('donations/', views.donations, name='donations'),
    path('donations/<str:id>/delete/', views.deleteDonation, name='delete_donations'),
    path('donations/<str:id>/edit/', views.editDonation, name='edit_donations'),
]
```

After we have made urlpatterns, when we click on the link of *a tag*, it will go to the route which is matched (in our case, it is second route) and then, it will go the the function in our views directory.

*views.py*

```
.....
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from django.shortcuts import render

def deleteDonation(request, id=None):
    donation = get_object_or_404(Donation, pk=id)
    donation.delete()
    return render(request, "delete_your_donation_.html")
```

Comment: Thank you for the extremely detailed answer, but when i click on the button I get the following error: `name 'response' is not defined
`

Comment: But the Donation does delete

Comment: sorry I mis typed that one. It is now updated. *render* function will take the template with your preferred name.

Comment: Thank you i was of help. Please let me know or recommend if you could find me some remote works. :)

Comment: I actually am developing a software, I am planning on launching it on github in the coming week. It is a donation application. Would this be something you would be interested in commiting to? We have a small dev team and we are planning to start paying our developers soon

Comment: Also, even though your code successfully deletes the Donation, I still get this error when trying to redirect: `Reverse for '<WSGIRequest: GET '/donations/77/delete/'>' not found. '<WSGIRequest: GET '/donations/77/delete/'>' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
`

Comment: I think I can. I guess??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235460/discussion-between-biplove-lamichhane-and-yojoeto).